# given $o(k), \neg o(n), \neg y(j), \forall x(y(x)\Rightarrow \neg o(x)), \exists x(y(x))$ prove $y(n)$ using Stanford university fitch system

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, natural-deduction, formal-proofs

Context:
This is related to [another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3689732/given-neg-p-and-p-vee-q-how-to-use-fitch-system-to-prove-q) I've recently asked BUT it is a different formulation of the same problem.
The orihinal problem is given [here](https://brilliant.org/practice/logic-puzzles/).

Solving the puzzle is very easy, my goal is to see if I can prove the solution using first-order logic, specifically using the Stanford University style [Fitch system](http://intrologic.stanford.edu/applications/herbrand.html).

My formulation (for this question) is more in line with the puzzle then the formulation in the previous question:

Kevin is the oldest hence $o(k)$

Nicholas is not the oldest hence $\neg o(n)$

Joseph is not the youngest hence $\neg y(j)$

I also added two axioms:

1. $\forall x(y(x)\Rightarrow\neg o(x))$
2. $\exists x(y(x))$

I was able to infer $\neg y(k)$, and I believe this, together with $\neg y(j)$ and with axiom 2 should prove $y(n)$ but I can't figure out a way to show that. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Instantiating the universal axiom with $k$ and contraposing it, you get $\lnot y(k)$. Now yo have $\lnot y(k)$ and $\lnot y(j)$.

Comment: But, in order to conclude, you have to state that the "universe" is made of $j,k,n$ only.

Comment: If you cannot use $=$, you may add: $y(k) \lor y(j) \lor y(n)$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA - Right, but I was assuming that the question was "Given these axioms ($\exists x \, y(x)$ and $\forall x \, (y(x) \to \lnot o(x))$ included), how can I conclude $y(n)$?". In my answer I tried to explain which is a "minimal" axiom to add in order to conclude $y(n)$. Of course, it is not easy  to give a rigorous account of "minimality", my idea was to add a an axiom that does not make anyone else superfluous. The axiom $y(n) \lor y(k) \lor y(j)$ makes the axiom $\exists x \, y(x)$ superfluous. Without any notion of minimality you could also add the axiom $y(n)$...

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco Well given that the original axioms are just whatever I thought would be enough to prove the solution, there is nothing special about the axiom $\exists x y(x)$. So for me, if my original set of axioms doesn't allow proving the answer in Stanford's proof assistant it is okay to replace $\exists x y(x)$ with $y(n)\vee y(k)\vee y(j)$ as $\exists x y(x)$ with $y(n)\vee y(k)\vee y(j)$ is still an axiom that is very much clear from the puzzle. The answer is pretty clear itself, but assuming we don't want to add it as an axiom, I think Mauro's suggestion makes sense.

Comment: In other words, since we are clearly talking about three brothers it makes sense to say that one is younger then the two others. A fourth brother may exist or not, but for simplicity we can define the y relation to mean "youngest of the mentioned three".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is another implicit premise in the problem: the domain is made up of $j$, $k$, $n$ and nobody else. In a formula,
\begin{align}
\forall x (x = j \lor x = k \lor x = n)
\end{align}

A sketch of the proof in a Fitch-style natural deduction system that $j(n)$ is the following:

1. By instantiating $\forall x(y(x) \to \neg o(x))$ with $k$ (universal elimination), you get $y(k) \to \neg o(k)$.
2. From $y(k) \to \neg o(k)$ and the premise $o(k)$ you can easily derive $\lnot y(k)$.
3. From the premises $\exists x \, y(x)$ and $\lnot y(j)$ and from the fact that $\lnot y(k)$ you can infer that $y(n)$, *provided that* you know that there are no other people in the domain (hence the need for the further premise $\forall x (x = j \lor x = k \lor x = n)$).

Otherwise, suppose there a fourth person (without a name). From $\exists x \, y(x)$ and $\lnot y(j)$ and $\lnot y(k)$ you cannot infer $y(n)$, because the youngest person might be the fourth person and not $n$.

Note that the hypothesis $\lnot o(n)$ is not necessary in the argument to prove $y(n)$.

Unfortunately, [Stanford's proof assistant](http://intrologic.stanford.edu/applications/herbrand.html) does not seem able to manage sentences with the identity symbol $=$ (it has no inference rules for it). Therefore, you cannot formulate the further axiom and use it to formalize the argument.
But there are many other proofs assistants for Fitch-style natural deduction that allow you to use the identity symbol $=$ and its inference rules, so you can use them to formalize the argument (in particular step 3).

Comment: Look in the comments for the original post, someone put a substitute axiom without identity symbol.

Comment: @Zack - I see, of course it is right but in my opinion it doesn't answer the original question. I explained my point of view as an answer to that comment.

Comment: Would it be possible to substitute the "=' symbol with $\leftrightarrow$? If not, what is the reason why?

Comment: If the answer is longer than a comment, I can ask this as a formal question linking back to this one for you to answer, if you feel so inclined.

Comment: @user400188 - No, it is impossible because $=$ and $\leftrightarrow$ are two completely different objects and play completely different roles. The _connective_ $\leftrightarrow$ relates two propositions (that are true or false) to create a _compound_ proposition. The identity $=$ is not a connective, it doesn't relate propositions. It is a _relational predicate_ that relates terms (i.e. individuals in your domain, not propositions) to create an _atomic_ proposition that can be true or false.